# error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, cmd, xunit

I am new to the .NET Core and xUnit. I would like to run xUnit tests from command line (CI pipeline). The project contains referenced dll (via `<PackageReference Include="some_library.dll">` in the csproj file). When running `dotnet test` from command line I get the following error:

```
 error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Running tests from within VS is without any problem.

How shall I run tests in such a way that the referenced library will be included also when running tests from cmd?

Comment: How did you use this library?

Comment: In the included dll there is implemented functionality which is used in the project under test. Not in my test class, but within the same assembly. However if I run the dotnet test from within the cmd, I get the error message saying that required namespace (from the dll) is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with mixing .NET Framework and .NET Core modules.

Running test by `dotnet test 'path_do_test_dll.dll'` is succesfull.